# MIT MAGIC KEY 1 error when running MPI programs compiled with openmpi 4.0.3 under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mpi

I am facing a weird issue. Whenever I run programs compiled with openmpi (version 4.0.3, the default on ubuntu 20.04 LTS), the following line is printed on the terminal Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE key.

I have managed to pinpoint it to programs that are compiled with openmpi. If i compile a dummy program in C, I manage to reproduce the error. If I compile the same program with mpich, the message does not appear.
Does anyone have a solution?
Is there a simple way I could downgrade or change the openmpi version on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation?

Thank you immensively